# The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</input>"

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I am getting the error on line number 29, which is the form closing tag below the button.

> org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: The element type "input" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "".

#### HTML

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">

    <head>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"></meta>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
        <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{signin.css}"></link>
        <title>login</title>
    </head>

    <body class="text-center">
        <form class="form-signin">
            <img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72">
            <h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
            <label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
            <input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" th:required="required">
            <label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
            <input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" th:required="required">
            <div class="checkbox mb-3">
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me</input>
                </label>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign in"></button>
        </form>

        <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
        <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    </body>

 </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

All tags should be closed. In your case `inputPassword` and `inputEmail` are not  closed.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
  xmlns:sec="http://www.thymeleaf.org/thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity3">
<head>
<!-- Required meta tags -->
<meta charset="utf-8"></meta>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"></meta>

<!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous"></link>
<link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{signin.css}"></link>
<title>login</title>
 </head>

<body class="text-center">
<form class="form-signin">
<img class="mb-4" src="https://getbootstrap.com/assets/brand/bootstrap-solid.svg" alt="" width="72" height="72"/>
<h1 class="h3 mb-3 font-weight-normal">Please sign in</h1>
<label for="inputEmail" class="sr-only">Email address</label>
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" th:required="required"/>
<label for="inputPassword" class="sr-only">Password</label>
<input type="password" id="inputPassword" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" th:required="required"/>
<div class="checkbox mb-3">
    <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value="remember-me"> Remember me</input>
    </label>
</div>
<button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" value="Sign in"></button>
 </form>

 <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: While it is a very good idea to always close tags, is it actually required for the form tag `input`? Can you provide some references?

Comment: Notice that he is using `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"`?

Answer (score 0):

Your input tag should be closed like this,

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" th:required="required" />
```

instead

```
<input type="email" id="inputEmail" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" th:required="required">
```

Comment: While it is a very good idea to always close tags, is it actually required for the form tag `input`? Can you provide some references?